# Flask: how to return an image to browser?

Tags: python

Well, I'm learning Flask. And now I want to show an image to browser like `127.0.0.1/test.png`.

But I can't find how to do that in document, and I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def showimage():
    with open('test.png', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This will only return some text. And I also want to know how to return some other type binary for download.

Comment: @wolendranh thanks, let me try it :)

Comment: u are welcome. that's first in Google for query - "return image in response flask"

Comment: @wolendranh Yes it is! I can't believe that why didn't I see it. However, thanks again.